How do I use the "Calculate Adjusted P-Values" extension in SPSS after conducting a general linear model?
For example, when conducting the general linear model (GLM), SPSS gives you a post-hoc option to apply multiple comparison corrections such as Bonferroni and Tukey etc. However, after installing the "Calculate Adjusted P-Values" extension in SPSS, the Benjamini-Hochberg (BH) correction only appears in the descriptive statistics option but NOT when I conduct the GLM. Do I need to create a variable of only my p-values from the GLM and then conduct the BH correction? If so, how do I do that?
I tried conducting the general linear model but the extension was not available to me there. How do I apply the benjamini-hochberg correction for my GLM?
